# Is the output of `Push.getPushKey()` always the same?

Tags: codenameone

I have to store server-side the output of `Push.getPushKey()`.

Is it always the same? Or is it better to make a REST request to update its value in the `init()`?

Can its value be `null`?

For example, is the following code in the `init()` a good approach? It waits for a not `null` PushKey, then it sends it and stops the timer.

```
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (Push.getPushKey() != null && authToken != null) {
                    Rest.post(Server.getRestServerURL() + "/updatePushKey")
                            .jsonContent()
                            .header("authToken", authToken)
                            .body(Push.getPushKey())
                            .fetchAsString((Response<String> response) -> {
                                if (isSuccessResponse(response)) {
                                    Log.p("PushKey successfully sent to the server", Log.INFO);
                                }
                            });
                    timer.cancel();
                }
            }
        }, 1000, 1000);
```

Thank you for your clarifications.

Comment: Citing from the docs "*Returns the push device key if the device was previously successfully registered for push otherwise returns null*". So, yes it can be `null`. And yes, the device token may change on iOS as well as on Android.

Comment: When do you send the pushKey to the server to keep it updated? I'm assuming that each user has only one device.

Comment: I just added code to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use a timer. You need to store this when the `registeredForPush` callback is invoked. Yes, it can update and it can be null if registration failed.